# Ошибки в описании привилегии "закрыть вопрос"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии

В описании привилегии ["закрыть вопрос"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) присутствуют следующие опечатки:

- > то, чтобы объявить, в конкретно заключается ...

  Пропущено `чём`.
- > В течение дня вы можете отдать 24 закрывающих голоса.
  >   Если за 4 дня ...

  Кажется, правильным было бы заменить `дня` на `суток`.
- > , то подпись будет выглядеть так:
  >   вернуть

  Нужно выделить `вернуть`, как это сделано ранее для `переоткрыть`, `закрыть`.
- > циклов закрытия и и возвращения

  Двойное `и`.
- > по данным пунктам о не более 1 раза

  Лишнее `о`.
- > за его закрытие,редактировать вопрос

  Пропущен пробел после запятой.
- > Правки или нужное количество просмотров с рецензией «Оставить Открытым» снимет вопрос с рассмотрения

  Вместо `снимет` нужно `снимут`.
- > то он будет повторно поставлено в очередь

  Вместо `поставлено` нужно `поставлен`.
- > повторяющихся вопросов -для удобства

  Пропущен пробел после `-`.
- > выпадет из очереди на возвращение Вопросы, отредактированные

  Пропущена точка после между предложениями.
- > будут появтся в списке повторов

  Опечатка в `появляться`.
- > После закрытия вопроса новые ответы не принимаются, а к заголовку добавляется [заблокировано]

Должно быть [требует правки]

P.S. Кстати, было бы неплохо для таких текстов предусмотреть возможность предложения правки, как это сделано для обычных вопросов/ответов. Чтобы вместо вопроса на "Мете" сразу поправить по месту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил текущую версию описания привилегии (опубликовано) и [написал переработанную версию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3201/).

Если вы видите, что какая–то страница справочного центра откровенно низкого качества (или просто должна быть переработана), пожалуйста, дайте знать! Я подготовлю первую версию и опубликую её на Мете для совместного редактирования.