# Улучшение описания привилегии «Закрывать и переоткрывать»

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Улучшение описания привилегии «[Закрывать и переоткрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)»

---

#### Что такое закрытие вопроса?

Закрытие – это демократический процесс, посредством которого сообщество голосованием выявляет вопросы не соответствующие тематике сайта, плохо сформулированные вопросы или уже заданные вопросы.

#### В каких случаях стоит голосовать за закрытие вопроса?

Вопросы следует закрывать если:

- они схожи с ранее заданными вопросами, и ответы на них, скорее всего, будут идентичными;
- они неясно сформулированы, слишком размыты или не понятно, в чем именно заключается вопрос;
- согласно [правилам](/help/on-topic), вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

Обратите внимание, что после того, как ваша репутация достигла уровня, когда вы можете голосовать за закрытие, вам больше не нужно отмечать вопрос тревогой, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора, который бы закрыл или переместил вопрос. Теперь ответственность за голосование лежит на вас.

Смотрите также: [Что изменится в сигналах тревоги после того, как я смогу голосовать за закрытие?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)

#### Как проголосовать за закрытие вопроса?

Количество уже отданных голосов за закрытие конкретного вопроса будет отражаться под телом вопроса в круглых скобках рядом с соответствующей ссылкой следующим образом:

```
закрыть (3)
```

Если голосов за закрытие еще нет, ссылка будет выглядеть так:

```
закрыть
```

Чтобы проголосовать за закрытие вопроса или просмотреть, как проголосовали другие участники – нажмите на ссылку «закрыть» под телом вопроса. Вы увидите список причин для закрытия с их описанием, а также количество отданных за них голосов.

[image: Диалог закрытия вопроса]

Если вы хотите проголосовать за какую–либо причину, то поставьте галку напротив её описания, затем нажмите кнопку «Закрыть». Если вы отметили, что вопрос «не по теме», вам необходимо пояснить, в чём конкретно заключается несоответствие, выбрав соответствующий пункт в дополнительном меню.

Чтобы вопрос был закрыт, необходимо, чтобы 5 участников проголосовало за закрытие, за исключением, когда вопрос закрывается как дубликат – в этом случае вопрос будет закрыт, как только за закрытие проголосует хотя бы один участник с золотым знаком по любой из меток вопроса.

В течение суток вы можете отдать 24 голоса за закрытие.

Если за 4 дня не набралось необходимого количество голосов за закрытие вопроса, то все отданные голоса считаются устаревшими и вопрос остается открытым. Каждый новый голос за закрытие запускает отсчет заново. Более того, [если вопрос не набрал 100 просмотров, то отсчет не запускается вовсе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

#### Что происходит, когда вопрос закрывается?

После закрытия вопроса новые ответы к нему не принимаются, а к заголовку добавляется статусная строка `[требует правки]`. Через 5 дней, если вопрос не будет открыт повторно, статус изменится на `[закрыто]`. Закрытые вопросы можно открыть повторно, путем голосования. Текущее количество голосов за повторное открытие отображается под телом вопросом в круглых скобках:

```
переоткрыть (3)
```

Число голосов, которые вопрос должен набрать для переоткрытия, будет указано во всплывающей подсказке. Если никто не проголосовал за повторное открытие вопроса, то ссылка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
переоткрыть
```

Хотя вопрос может пройти несколько циклов закрытия и повторного открытия, каждый участник может участвовать в голосовании не более одного раза. Если вопрос был закрыт, его можно объединить с другим, переместить на другой сайт нашей сети или даже удалить.

#### Альтернатива закрытию вопроса

Если вам не хватает репутации, чтобы проголосовать за закрытие, или вы уже использовали все голоса за текущий день, вы можете поступить иначе.

- Если вопрос является дубликатом, добавьте комментарий со ссылкой на аналогичный вопрос.
- Если содержание вопроса совершенно неприемлемо (например, вопрос содержит спам или оскорбления), [отметьте его тревогой](/help/privileges/flag-posts).

#### Просмотр голосов за закрытие или повторное открытие вопроса

Эта привилегия позволяет просматривать две специальные очереди: одна с вопросами, которые, вероятно, следует [закрыть](/review/close), другая с теми, которые следует [открыть повторно](/review/reopen).

Каждый вопрос, получивший голос за закрытие или отмеченный сигналом тревоги, появится в «очереди на закрытие». Если вопрос попал в этот список, участники могут голосовать за его закрытие, редактировать вопрос или рекомендовать оставить «как есть». Правки или необходимое количество голосов с рецензией «оставить открытым» снимут вопрос с рассмотрения и немедленно запустят таймер «срока давности» голосования за его закрытие. Если после остановки голосования вопрос получает еще один закрывающий голос, то он будет повторно поставлен в очередь на закрытие. Вопрос получивший голос за закрытие как дубликат, также попадет в список вопросов–дубликатов. Для удобства просмотра список спрятан во вкладке наверху.

Аналогичным образом в очереди на повторное открытие будут появляться те вопросы, голосование по которым открыто в данный момент. Участники могут голосовать за повторное открытие вопросов, редактировать их или оставлять вопросы закрытыми. Набрав необходимо количество голосов «оставить закрытым», вопрос пропадает из очереди на переоткрытие. Система автоматически отправляет вопросы отредактированные в течении 5 дней после закрытия в очередь на повторное открытие. У вопросов, которые вы уже просмотрели, наверху появится дополнительная панель, чтобы их было лучше видно. Таким же образом вопросы, отмеченные как дубликаты, будут появляться в списке дубликатов, расположенном во вкладке наверху.

Comment: Имхо, надо поменять все `вы` на `Вы`.

Comment: @alexolut На эту тему у нас была [дискуссия](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489/6). Сошлись на использовании «вы», как я понимаю.

Comment: значит, хорошо, что я не полез править текст, а оставил комментарий :)